# Django get_models with models/__init.py__

Tags: python, django

I'm having a problem using get_model and get_models in django

I have several models under models/

```
 models/blog.py
 models/tags.py
 models/users.py
 models/comments.py
 models/category.py
```

And a `models/__init.py__`

```
from myapp.models.blog import *
from myapp.models.tags import *
from myapp.models.users import *
from myapp.models.comments import *   
from myapp.models.category import *
```

However in my views.py I have some code to use get_model

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
blog_class = get_model('myapp', 'blog') #Returns none
```

When I try `get_models('myapp')` it returns an empty list.

I also tried

```
print(get_app('myapp'))
```

Which returns:

```
<module 'myapp.models' from '/var/www/myapp/models/__init__.pyc'>
```

And if I try to iterate over it

```
for model in get_models(get_app('myapp')):
    print(model)
```

It does nothing. Is there anything I'm missing or failing to spot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you haven't defined your models in the app's `models.py`, you must explicitly set the [`app_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.app_label) option for each model.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'myapp'
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. It turned out to be a case issue between Myapp and myapp.